# Function to insert rows in excel template with data from a listbox not working properly

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am having an issue when my listbox items contain more items/rows when inserting the list data in the excel sheet. The first set data for location 1 always works great and inserts everything the way it should but then sometimes location 2 will work if i mess with the function enough. I can't get anything after the second location to insert the values properly and it always messes up and inserts rows into the wrong places or messes up the sum formula at the end of the location section.

Is there a way to insert rows with a random listcount variable? The way i have it setup at the moment is if there are more than 15 items in the listbox then it needs to insert the x number after the listcount and then do the same for the rest of the sheet for each location.

```
Private Sub testbtn_Click()
Dim excelApp As Excel.Application
Dim targetWB As Workbook
Dim targetRange As Range
Set excelApp = New Excel.Application
Dim fName As String
Dim xcelObj As Object
Set xcelObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

fName = ("Test - " & Format(Date, "mm-dd-yyyy"))

If FileExists(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "template.xlsm") = False Then Exit Sub

If FileExists(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & fName & ".xlsm") = False Then
xcelObj.CopyFile ThisWorkbook.Path & "\template.xlsm", ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & fName & ".xlsm"
End If

Set targetWB = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & fName & ".xlsm")

Dim n As Integer
L = lb1.List
n = (UBound(L) + 1) - 15


Call Sheet_AddLBRangeTest(targetWB, 1, 30, dtp.lb1, dtp.lb2, "A16", "B16")

Call Sheet_AddLBRangeTest(targetWB, 1, 51 + n, dtp.lb1, dtp.lb2, "A" & 37 + n, "B" & 37 + n)

Call Sheet_AddLBRangeTest(targetWB, 1, 72 + n + 7, dtp.lb1, dtp.lb2, "A" & 58 + n + 7, "B" & 58 + n + 7)

Call Sheet_AddLBRangeTest(targetWB, 1, 93 + n + 14, dtp.lb1, dtp.lb2, "A" & 79 + n + 14, "B" & 79 + n + 14)

Call Sheet_AddLBRangeTest(targetWB, 1, 114 + n + 21, dtp.lb1, dtp.lb2, "A" & 100 + n + 21, "B" & 100 + n + 21)

'Call Sheet_AddLBRange(targetWB, 1, dtp.lb1, dtp.lb2, "D16", "F16")



targetWB.Close (True)
excelApp.Quit

End Sub
```

'this is from my module
'function to check if file exists

```
Function FileExists(sFullPath As String) As Boolean
    Dim fOBJ As Object
    Set fOBJ = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
    FileExists = fOBJ.FileExists(sFullPath)
End Function
```

' function to add the listboxes to the excel sheet

```
Public Sub Sheet_AddLBRangeTest(Wb As Workbook, SN As Integer, RN As Integer, lb1 As MSForms.listbox, lb2 As MSForms.listbox, Cell1 As String, Cell2 As String)
    Dim L As Variant
    Dim L2 As Variant
    Dim n As Integer
    L = lb1.List
    L2 = lb2.List

        If lb1.ListCount = 0 Then
                Wb.Sheets(SN).Range(Cell1).Resize(1, 1).Value = 0
        Else
            If UBound(L) + 1 > 15 Then
                n = (UBound(L) + 1) - 15
                Wb.Sheets(SN).Rows(RN).Resize(n).Insert
            End If
                Wb.Sheets(SN).Range(Cell1).Resize(UBound(L) + 1, 1).Value = L
        End If

        If lb2.ListCount = 0 Then
                Wb.Sheets(SN).Range(Cell2).Resize(1, 1).Value = 0
        Else
                Wb.Sheets(SN).Range(Cell2).Resize(UBound(L2) + 1, 1).Value = L2
        End If
    End Sub
```

[This is a screen shot of my template excel file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OljgH.png)

[Messes up here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lN3hJ.png)

Comment: That is way to much code. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Why don't you get rid of the 15 empty rows and insert an empty line in every case?

Comment: This is new territory for me unfortunately. I have tried that route and couldn't figure out how to insert the rows properly in my template sheet. I was having the same issue but 95% of the time it's under 15 items that is why i adjusted it. Could you provide an example on how i would do that? Thank you!

Comment: @sam I did read that and did exactly as it said. Directly says to do just what i did. "Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem. For help with this, read How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example." I took every part out of my program except what i needed to reproduce my issue.